# Adding the results of a function to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Hi im just trying to add the results of a numerical function to an array to be displayed in a table but i am getting nowhere, i would like to add some sample code but it would just be a mess

at the moment i have something along these lines

```
var numpacks = function(width,length)
{
return ((width * length)/2);
}   

var calculate = function(e)

var result = document.getElementById('calculate');
```

and i am trying to get the results of the calculation into an array to be put into a table

i have been trying this

```
var report =[];
report.push(numpacks)
```

but all it returns is the function itself not the result

Comment: Please edit your question and add tags identifying your language/environment and provide more details.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the code is a mess. Clean it up, and post what you have tried.

Comment: well so far i have something a bit like this

Comment: you have to call the function with its parameters.

Comment: thanks but how would i go about this?

Comment: Still need more information describing what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information its impossible to know exactly what you want, but assuming its an integer returning function, but you could try something like:

```
int[] array = new int[randomNumber];

for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {
    array[i] = myFunction()
}

int myFunction(){
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i have been trying this
>
> `var report =[]; report.push(numpacks)` but all it returns is the
>   function itself not the result

Of course it does, you are setting numpacks to the function in the first line

> `var numpacks = function(width,length)`

you want to declare a function

```
function halfArea(width,length)
{
   return (width * length) / 2;
}
```

And then you want to call it

```
var result = halfArea(10, 20);
```

And then you can add the result

```
var report =[];
report.push(result)
```